# System for email verification in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email-verification

Is a pre-made system available to confirm a new user's email address for an ASP.NET site?  I'm using the pre built Authentication and Role providers.  The system should be able to send email to a user when they're added to the system that requires them to click a link, that link would then "unlock" the account.  Users shouldn't be able to login until their email is verified.  I could probably figure out how to roll this on my own but I'd prefer to use a standard method if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just include the link and *salt the password*. You'd probably have this hand-coded in less time than it would take you to find a shrink wrap version.

Some info on the salt:
http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp

Comment: I have to say you should completely disregard the linked article on salting the password. Use System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx